# Apache MySQL on OS X control script

Tags: mysql, macos, shell, terminal, osx-snow-leopard

So I configured apache and mysql on my OS X Snow Leopard, everything works fine so far. What I want to do now is create a script that allows me to start/stop the services in a glimpse.

Stopping the daemon works fine with

```
mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
```

The problem is controlling mysql starting. To start the daemon directly on the terminal, I use

```
> mysqld_safe
[CTRL-Z]
> bg
```

But: How can I simulate this in a script file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just send the process to the background?

```
mysql_safe &
```

You could also create a log file during the startup:

```
mysql_safe --log-error=/tmp/mysqld.log &
```

Also you want more validations, checking the status of the servers etc. You can take a look at how we do it in the [BitNami MAMPStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/mampstack). The script for MySQL it is placed in /mysql/scripts/ctl.sh

Comment: Those scripts seem quite sophisticated... Can I just use them as they are, of course configuring them to use my libraries and settings?

Comment: I have not tried them outside of the stacks, but they are quite general. You should be able to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysqld.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
        "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.mysql.mysqld</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/local/bin/mysqld</string>
            <string>--datadir=/var/mysql</string>
            <string>--skip_networking</string>
        </array>
        <key>UserName</key>
        <string>_mysql</string>
        <key>GroupName</key>
        <string>_mysql</string>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And run:

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

Note that, if you're installing mysql to somewhere other than `/usr/local`, you should of course change the path to mysqld accordingly.